# Как сделать всплыващее окно при событие "В корзину" в битрикс 1с?

Tags: битрикс

Не пойму как сделать всплывающее окно при событие  "В корзину" в битрикс 1с ? Я написал следующий код, но ничего не выходит. Буду рад любой помощи!

```
<script>
BX.addCustomEvent('ADD2BASKET', function () { alert("получилось") }

</script>
```